# Migracion repositorios Gitlab a Github

Tags: git, github, gitlab, migracion

Buen dia tengo el siguiente caso actualmente en Gitlab tengo unos 300 respositorios pero tengo que pasarlos a Github la primera opcion que pense fue hace un bash que me hiciera este proceso pero no sabria como hacerlo, la segunda es encontrar algun software gratuito que me haga la migracion pero no he encontrado mucha informacion, agradeceria la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Hola intenta probar el siguiente script

```
#!/bin/bash
github_username="<TU USUARIO DE GITHUB>"
gitlab_username="<TU USUARIO DE GITLAB>"
gitlab_access_token="<TU TOKEN DE ACCESO PERSONAL DE GITLAB>"
github_repos=(
  "https://github.com/$github_username/nombrerepositorio.git"
  "https://github.com/$github_username/nombrerepositorio.git"
)
for repo in "${github_repos[@]}"
do
  git clone $repo
  repo_name=$(basename "$repo" .git)
  cd "$repo_name"
  git remote set-url origin "https://gitlab.com/$gitlab_username/$repo_name.git"
  git push origin master
  cd ..
done
```

Comment: No creo que esto le sirva al OP, por que de todas formas tendría que tomarse el trabajo de crear previamente en Github los 300 repositorios. Para automatizar esta parte hay que usar el cliente de terminal propio de github: `gh`